# .Net FtpWebRequest fails sometimes

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I try to list file details using FtpWebRequest but very frequently it fails with a WebException and shows error 530 User not logged in.

How is this possible, that it works some of the time using the same credentials?

Excerpt from code:

```
        reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(ftpuri));
        reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
        reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
        string[] downloadFiles = new string[0];
            reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
            WebResponse response = reqFTP.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            downloadFiles = reader.ReadToEnd().Replace("\r\n", "¤").Split('¤');
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
```

Comment: I have had this exact problem. It seems to happen more often when I have already been connected to the server for a while, then I change directory and do a list.

Comment: Your problem is similar to the bug the built in Windows Explorer FTP (ie: Internet Explorer integrated into Explorer.exe) where after navigating a directory it would "lose" your credentials and repeatedly ask you to login. I've never heard of this behavior when using dotnet, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting

```
reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
```

and possibly if the above does not work

```
reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
```

I found that setting these to false reduced the occurrences of this error (which is generated by the FTP server) considerably.